# Error : Can not find protocol declaration for OFFlickrAPIRequestDelegate

Tags: iphone, sharekit

I am working on an application in which I implement ShareKit for sharing. It was working fine on Xcode 4.2. After I updated Xcode to 4.5.1, it gives me the error :

> Can not find protocol declaration for OFFlickrAPIRequestDelegate

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the solution for me was to upgrade the ShareKit module.

Is has to do with a problem in AvailabilityMacros.h and iOs6

This post pointed me in the right direction: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/objectiveflickr/wWwA8jiNNlc